# How to know what domains other clients visit if I have no access to the router?

Tags: sniffer

As a client computer, I am behind a router to which I have no access. Is it possible for me to know the domains or IP addresses that other clients visit?

I want to know which clients often download files because it really makes the network so busy.

My computer and other clients are in the same LAN (192.168.1.xxx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mayank Sharma advice is technically right but might not work in most of the environments because organizations/individuals use network switches nowadays which route data only to the intended recipient. Wireshark would work only where network hubs are used which broadcast the traffic to every node in the network.

In order to sniff traffic in switched environments you have to perform MITM (Man In The Midddle) through ARP poisoning. Once you perform MITM, you will be able to sniff data of the other nodes in a switch environment. I don't know if you are authorized to perform sniffing or MITM on the other machines so make sure you have prior approval.

In order to perform MITM you can use many open and closed source tools. [Cain and Abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html) and [Ettercap](http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) are two tools that are very easy to perform MITM. Cain and Abel is only for Windows platform while Ethercap works fine on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Your question provides very limited information. It seems that you are in the same LAN as the people you are willing to monitor. In such a case in order to monitor the traffic you can use the [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) tool to capture packets and analyse all the unencrypted content (passive sniffing).

I am assuming that you are not in a switched network because then you will not be able to see the packets from your client machine. In such cases you may need to go for active sniffing techniques (e.g. MITM). Make sure not to violate any security policies that your organization has in place.

In your case simply looking at the DNS traffic you will be able to find out what websites people are trying to access. And then accordingly you will have to monitor individual IPs to find out who is consuming the bandwidth.